# Do I need to boil kidneys?

Tags: meat, boiling

I was just speaking to someone in the sci-fi chat today when the subject of kidneys came up:

> [Kidneys aren't "bad" in that they have the consistency and taste of muscle/meat... but they're very bitter even after having been prepared. I think you're supposed to boil them.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7276043#7276043)

I've never had boiled kidneys before, nor do I intend to. But the poster of that comment also mentioned that I should *Think about what's in kidneys for a moment.*

So here I am to ask, should I be boiling them to get rid of their previous contents or are they safe to fry etc?

Comment: ps: Shouldn't the posted question be titled as something other than "my kidneys" as if it's your own remains being cooked?

Comment: @zanlok I understood that so, But some of the urine is still in the kidneys before reaching the urethers. And that makes kidneys have a huge urine smelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to eat kidneys unwashed. But almost nobody enjoys smelling ammonia, urea or nitrogenous wastes in general when eating food.

You can boil them to remove that taste.

But a better alternative is to leave them covered with salt in a colander (so what *everybody thinks there's in kidneys for a moment*  will fall off). Leave there for about two hours, and then rinse them with water with vinegar.

---

Source: I asked a [nephrologyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephrology) who prepares one of the best [*Riñones al Jerez*](http://www.google.es/search?q=ri%C3%B1ones%20al%20jerez&aq=f&ie=UTF-8) (in English *kidneys in Sherry*) I've ever tasted.

Comment: And here I thought you had to put them in pie together with steak....

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Yeah steak and kidney pie or pudding, can't beat it!

Comment: Well, *Riñones al Jerez* is a typical dish where I am from. I've also eaten just fried when I was a kid (with liver: supposedly for being healthy). I'm sure there are many tasty recipes for kidneys.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to boil them.

Skin them, split them lengthways without separating them in two halves and remove the cores. Soak in cold water for 5 or 10 mins.

Fry, grill or sauté them or braise/steam them with Steak in a pie or suet pudding.

Just to add, it's sheep's kidneys that generally get used.

Comment: Why the soaking?

Comment: @Pureferret You should generally soak most offal (liver, kidneys etc.) in water or milk before cooking to remove some of the strong flavour from them.

Comment: I've seen recipes calling for pork, beef, lamb or poultry kidneys, besides sheep ones. It depends on the recipe (or on what you can get, I guess). I really don't know why ones would be preferred ver others (except that poultry ones fit whole in your mouth).